# How to add SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 support to Mailsetting in web.config in asp.net webform 4.5 application

Tags: asp.net, ssl, webforms, smtp, web-config

I have old asp.net webform application (4.5) and due to security TLS has been upgraded to TLS 1.2 & due to which Mail feature which depend on TLS 1.0 are not working.

Below code works for if server supports TLS 1.0 but on new server TLS 1.0 & TLS 1.1 is disabled so below code in web.config is not working any more, it doesn't give any error but email are not working for default functionality such as password reset for asp.net membership module which depend on below code defined in web.config

```
 <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="noreply@mailserver.com">
        <network host="outlook.office365.com" port="587" enableSsl="true" userName="no-reply@mailserver.com" password="Passward" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

if same was to be done in code .cs file then we can add following code and it will add TLS 1.2 support and code works but i am not sure how to add same to the mailsetting in web.config for SMTP in above mentioned code. any pointer as i am not able to find syntax for same on net

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

Comment: Have u found out the answer to this?

Comment: sicko, I stopped looking as i was not able to find a working solution. Rather than making changes in web.config i did changes in .cs files where is am using code to send email..